# The best way to refresh JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, thread-sleep

Can anyone tell me the best way to refresh a JTable ? I have tried to use `table.repaint()` from another thread, but I don't know if this is the best way.

My code:

**Class: Model**

```
public class CLS_ValueUpdater extends Thread {

    private String sRowName;
    private String sValue;

    public CLS_ValueUpdater(String sRowName) {
        this.sRowName = sRowName;
        this.start();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.sValue;
    }

    public String getRowName() {
        return sRowName;
    }

    public void setRowName(String sRowName) {
        this.sRowName = sRowName;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                this.sValue = String.valueOf(i);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Class: Controller**

```
public class CLS_Controller extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5603593230985106202L;
    private String[] sArrColumns = { "Nombre", "Valor" };

    private ArrayList<CLS_ValueUpdater> tListUpdater = new ArrayList<CLS_ValueUpdater>();

    public CLS_Controller() {
        super();
    }

    public void addRow(String sName) {
        this.tListUpdater.add(new CLS_ValueUpdater(sName));
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void deleteRow(int iIndex) {
        this.tListUpdater.remove(iIndex);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int iColumn) {
        return this.sArrColumns[iColumn];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return this.sArrColumns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.tListUpdater.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int iRow, int iColumn) {
        CLS_ValueUpdater tValueUpdater = this.tListUpdater.get(iRow);

        switch (iColumn) {
        case 0:
            return tValueUpdater.getRowName();
        case 1:
            return tValueUpdater.getValue();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object oValue, int iRow, int iColumn) {
        CLS_ValueUpdater tValueUpdater = this.tListUpdater.get(iRow);

        switch (iColumn) {
        case 0:
            tValueUpdater.setRowName(oValue.toString());
            break;
        }

        this.fireTableCellUpdated(iRow, iColumn);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getColumnClass(int iColumn) {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Class: View**

```
public class FRM_Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private CLS_Controller tModel = new CLS_Controller();
    private JTextField textField;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FRM_Main window = new FRM_Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public FRM_Main() {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 476, 283);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                tModel.addRow(textField.getText());
            }
        });

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Delete");

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(gl_panel
                .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(
                                        gl_panel.createParallelGroup(
                                                Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        scrollPane,
                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        440, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addGroup(
                                                        Alignment.TRAILING,
                                                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        textField,
                                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(
                                                                        ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        btnNewButton)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(
                                                                        ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                                                        216,
                                                                        Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                .addComponent(
                                                                        btnNewButton_1)))
                                .addContainerGap()));
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(gl_panel
                .createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(
                        gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(scrollPane,
                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 194,
                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(
                                        gl_panel.createParallelGroup(
                                                Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                .addComponent(btnNewButton_1)
                                                .addComponent(
                                                        textField,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(btnNewButton))
                                .addContainerGap(80, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        table = new JTable();
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setModel(tModel);

        new tableUpdater(table);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);

    }
}

class tableUpdater extends Thread {

    private JTable tTable;

    public tableUpdater(JTable tTable) {
        this.tTable = tTable;
        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                tTable.repaint();

                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So is there any elegant way to autoupdate the JTable? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Way too much code for this question. Why don't you crop it to just show the bit where you update the JTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to use table.repaint() from another thread

If another thread is not the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) your table is not gonna to be repainted.

You want to update your jtable with a progress bar. You may interested using `SwingWorker` . Here is a complete [example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/).

```
class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker <String,String>{ //what params you want here 

@Override
protected String doInBackground()throws Exception{

   //here you download heavy task
    //and you call publish() when you want 
}

@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks){
  // here you updated your gui 
   //setValueAt(row,col); and fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
}

@Override
protected void done(){
  //here is called when doInBackGround is finished
}
```

}

So then you have to call `setValue(int row, int column)` and `fireTableCellUpdated(int row,int col);` with partial results that swingWorker gives you.

BTW When you insert a row

```
 public void addRow(String sName) {
        this.tListUpdater.add(new CLS_ValueUpdater(sName));
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
 }
```

May be is better to call

`void fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow)`

Comment: You dont understand me... I need to update the inserted value all the time, because i'm writting a small multidownloader and i need to see the download progress value, so the Jtable will need to update automatically all the time for the download progress. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for response.

Comment: i understand now.. you may interested about `SwingWorker`

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa Why don't you use a `JProgressBar` ?

Comment: @Radu Murzea - Actually, the question here is to know how to do one thing and not seek alternative. But thanks for the reply.

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa i edited answer, hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you very much nachokk!!! Is just what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc of `DefaultTableModel#setValueAt ()` says:

> Sets the object value for the cell at column and row. aValue is the
>   new value. This method will generate a tableChanged notification.

So if you change the content by calling `model.setValueAt()`, that will also trigger a repaint.

Note: `model` is the `TableModel` of your `JTable`.

Comment: This.  `setValueAt` is all you need.  If your view is not updating when you use `setValueAt`, you have a bug in your table model.

Comment: My code is MVC implementation. I need to autoupdate the each item of the Jtable all the time (like some progress value).

Comment: So are you asking how to update your table model?  Or what.

Comment: he is not using defaultTableModel

Answer (score -1):

If you want to refresh your table every 1 seconds, use a separate Thread that does the refresh ; do not forget to use invokeLater method.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  public void run()
  {
     while(true)
     {
       Thread.sleep(1000);  
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         public void run() 
         {
           _tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
         }
       });
     }
  }
}).start();
```

Comment: I had tried that method but if I have selected any row of JTable  it is deselected when it refresh, however with Jtable.repaint does not happen. Sorry for bad english. Thanks for response!

Comment: sceleton is proper, all updates must be done on EDT, but don't to call any notifiers out of model, this is important part of model, see answer by @nachokk,

Comment: -1 (emphasizing @mKorbel) don't fire events on behalf of a model - **NEVER-EVER**